# Storing loop output in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I want to know how to store the values of the complete loop output into a single dataframe in R. For example,

```
for(i in unique(x$id)){
    .
    .
    .
    y=output of one iteration}
```

At the end of each iteration, I am getting the output in y. But I want to store output of all iterations into y. How do I do that in R?

Comment: You should seriously consider using `lapply`. It's designed for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can begin with y as an empty `data.frame` as in: `y <- data.frame()`. Then bind the rows to this data.frame at the end of each iteration as in: `y <- rbind.data.frame(y, [output of one interation])`. But you can also make this a little more tight by wrapping it in an `lapply` and `do.call` as in:

```
y <- do.call(rbind.data.frame,
             lapply(unique(x$id),
                    function(i){
       ...;
       return([output of one iteration])}))
```

Answer (score 23):

You can do this simply by

```
y  <- NULL;
for (i in unique(x$id))
 { 
  tmp <- [output of one iteration]
  y <- rbind(y, tmp)
 }
```

Comment: Don't grow an object in a loop. It's slow. Pre-allocate to the size you need!

Comment: How do you mean? Could you please show what needs to be fixed here in order for the code to run faster? @Roland

Comment: Inadvertent [Shlemiel the painter’s algorithm](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/)?