# Unable to store loop output in R

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to store the loop output. However, my dataset is quite big and it crashes Rstudio whenever I try to View it. I have tried different techniques such as the functions in `library(iterators)` and `library(foreach)`, but it is not doing what I want it to do. I am trying to take a row from my main table (Table A)(number of rows 54000) and then a row from another smaller table (Table B)(number of rows = 6). I have also took a look at [Storing loop output in a dataframe in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862933/storing-loop-output-in-a-dataframe-in-r) but it doesn't really allow me to view my results.

The code takes the first row from Table A and then iterates it 6 times through table B and then outputs the result of each iteration then moves to Table A's second row. As such my final dataset should contain 324000 (54000*6) observations.

Below is the code that provides me with the correct observations (but I am unable to view it to see it the values are being correctly calculated) and a snippet of Table A and Table B.

```
output_ratios <-  NULL

for (yr in seq(yrs)) {
  if (is.na(yr) == 'TRUE') {
    numerator=0
    numerator1=0
    numerator2=0
    denominator=0
  } else {
    numerator=Table.B[Table.B$PERIOD == paste("PY_", yr, sep=""), c("1")]
    denominator=Table.B[Table.B$PERIOD == paste("PY_", yr, sep=""), c("2")]
    denom=Table.A[, "1"] + (abs(Table.A[, "1"])*denominator)
    num=Table.A[, "2"] + (abs(Table.A[, "2"])*numerator)
    new.data$1=num
    new.data$2=denom
    NI=num / denom
    NI_ratios$NI=c(NI)
    output_ratios <<- (rbind(output_ratios, NI))
  }
}
```

TABLE B:

```
        PERIOD     1          2                3          4          5
1          PY_1  0.21935312 -0.32989691       0.12587413 -0.28323699 -0.04605116
2          PY_2  0.21328526  0.42051282      -0.10559006  0.41330645  0.26585064
3          PY_3 -0.01338112 -0.03971119      -0.06641667 -0.08238231 -0.05323772
4          PY_4  0.11625091  0.01127819       0.07114166  0.08501516  0.55676498
5          PY_5 -0.01269256 -0.02379182       0.39115278 -0.03716100  0.63530682
6          PY_6  0.69041864  0.51034273       0.59290357  0.78571429 -0.48683736
```

TABLE A:

```
1      2      3     4
1     25     3657    2258
2     23     361361  250    
3     24     35      000 
4     25     362     502      
5     25     1039    502
```

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: when you say it iterates 6 times, you mean that it duplicates the row from table B six times ?

Comment: first, the code is long.. what are you trying to achieve?? eg numerator and denominator are exactly equal to each other. second there is no mention of `new.data` before its use. also there is nothing called `NI_stress` while you are outputting it.Lastly, whatever you are doing can be done by other functions other than iteration

Comment: Thank Onyambu, I have made the edits. Regarding new.data, I was trying to store the value for num and denum for debugging purpose. @yolo, It does not duplicate the row from table B. it takes a row from Table A and then multiplies it to Table B row by row (Table B contains 6 rows).